# Signing issue with `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`

Tags: git, zsh, git-commit, gnupg

#### What I am trying to do

I would like to sign my git commits with a gpg key, I have the line `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` in my .zshrc file. I am able create a signed commit when I source my .zshrc.

#### Issue I am facing

I have found that in vscode integrated terminal (I haven't tried this in a iTerm window) after a while that I will get `failed to sign commit, make sure to set email, username`. but once I export again it works as expected.

I also downloaded the gpg suite to allow me to still sign commits, and that seems to make this issue go away. but I would prefer it to be a temporary solution while I figure this out.

I'm not sure what would cause the GPG_TTY to "expire".

#### Current configuration

Im am using a Mac, with zsh, and Powerlevel 10k.
(this issue existed before I started using p10k)

Any, and all help is appreciated!!

Comment: The GPG_TTY setting, once set, probably shouldn't expire, but since VSCode is a Microsoft product, I wouldn't put anything past it.  I suspect, though, that the setting isn't even making it into the VSCode startup, and that the signing is working until the gpg-agent timeout hits. When you start up a new zsh, you end up refreshing the agent, or something.

Comment: @torek yeah that sounds like what I was thinking was happening. Do you know if there is a way to track when the gpg-agent times out and re-export the TTY?

Comment: Not sure about tracking it. When I was using gpg signing (for package-making, for apt) a colleague and I found a way to set our gpg keys to last much longer. I forget what that was offhand though.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that!